# replacing apache with nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server

I have a fairly popular site on the internet (15K visitors/day) on an micro Amazon instance.

Users are now competing for CPU-time.

Can I take my configuration to nginx?

How much 'work' is it?

Comment: The amount of "work" is directly proportional to the complexity of the configuration you're migrating from.  That's about the best answer we can give with the little information provided.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I take my configuration to nginx?

Probably.  nginx can do most things that Apache can do.. but it depends on your config.

> How much 'work' is it?

Again, it depends.  If your configuration is relatively simple, it'll take 5 minutes.  If it's incredibly complex, hours.

Comment: 7 domains with some custom log file paths, some htaccess files with rewrite rules some php .. that's it i think

Comment: You will need to port the use of the htaccess files to nginx format and locations.

Comment: @ulvund Also, if the reason your users are competing for CPU time is actually the PHP code, not much will be won by migrating to ngnix.

Comment: No PHP code on the popular pages. I do however run some ruby crawlers on the side